# default form_with NOT remote nor expecting to respond via JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Class `shop`

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shopzones, allow_destroy: true
```

while the shops_controller defines the action and attempts to define the strong parameters

```
def shopzone
  @shopzone = Shopzone.new
  @shopzone.save
end

def shopzone_params  # in addition to the def shop_params method
  params.require(:shopzone).permit(:shop_id, :name, :sequence, :area)
end
```

A form

```
 <%= form_with url: shopzone_shop_path(id: @shop.id) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field 'shopzone[shop_id]', value: @shop.id %>
    <div class='grid-x grid-padding-x'>
      <div class='cell small-3 alert'>
        <%= t('name') %>
        <%= f.text_field 'shopzone[name]' %>
        <%= t('sequence') %>:
        <%= f.number_field 'shopzone[sequence]' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='grid-x grid-padding-x'>
      <div class='cell small-12 text-center'>
        <%= f.submit t('create'), class: 'button' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

But it does not render `data-remote="true"` as is expected by default.

```
<form action="/shops/3/shopzone" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

Upon submission the parameters are logged but towards an expected HTML response

```
Processing by ShopsController#shopzone as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "shopzone"=>{"shop_id"=>"3", "name"=>"central", "sequence"=>"1"
```

If the form is edited to

```
<%= form_with(url: shopzone_shop_path(id: @shop.id), local: false) do |f| %>
```

then the  data-remote renders

```
<form action="/shops/3/shopzone" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

However, the server response is still expecting to handle HTML

```
Processing by ShopsController#shopzone as HTML
[...]
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ShopsController#shopzone is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
```

Thus the first oddity is rails' purported default behaviour not kicking in?
If the controlelr action is appended with

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

The process runs

```
Started POST "/shops/3/shopzone" for ::1 at 2021-06-11 10:34:28 +0200
Processing by ShopsController#shopzone as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "shopzone"=>{"shop_id"=>"3", "name"=>"central", "sequence"=>"1" [...]
```

but then complains about the validations which exist on the model

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Shop must exist, Sequence can't be blank, Name can't be blank):
```

which is contrary to the parameters submitted.  Inspecting the params in the action before save `puts    @shopzone.inspect`  effectively returns nil params.

Thus something about the nested attributes is throwing default behaviours off.

What is best course to process the request as unobtrusive JS ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like correct use of nested params. your form object should be a Shop and it should use fields_for for the nested shop zone.  Otherwise just drop the nested params since you're not really using them

Comment: Yes, I went that route.  However, it had a series of issues and ended up not being that simple.  There is a strightforward way `Shopzone.create!` with the params.  Alas, those are not 'strong' per se.

Comment: At least move this functionality to the shopzone controller then, it makes no sense for it to go through shops. your form seems to not change anything on the shop, so why is it going to shops_controller? and remove the nested_attributes if u go this route.

Comment: There is no necessity for a controller per se; trying to handle the class with only a model definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll refer to part of your question since you are raising a couple of issues:

Since Rails 6.1 form_with is non ajax by default so to make it ajax you have to pass `local: false` or set the global config option (`config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms`) to true.

Compare form_with [Rails 5.2 documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/) .

> :local - By default form submits are remote and unobtrusive XHRs. Disable remote submits with local: true.

With [Rails 6.1](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)

> :local - By default form submits via typical HTTP requests. Enable
> remote and unobtrusive XHRs submits with local: false. Remote forms
> may be enabled by default by setting
> config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms = true

Another thing I see is you're not doing anything with the shopzone params, but even if this will work reconsider how you built this, this is not standard use of [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

```
def shopzone
  @shopzone = Shopzone.new(shopzone_params) # you forgot this!
  @shopzone.save
end

def shopzone_params  # in addition to the def shop_params method
  params.require(:shopzone).permit(:shop_id, :name, :sequence, :area)
end
```

Comment: `shopzone_params`  needed to be set to run the action properly- which explains the nil params upon their inspection.